# Translating a code of c++ to Java without success

Tags: java, c++, minimum-spanning-tree

I am making a program to compute minimum cost routes, using minimal spanning trees. I did my implementation in c + + but I could not make a graphical interface to read the input file, so I decided to pass it to Java language and create the interface using Netbeans. Herés my code in c++:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where any of the following arrays are initialised:

```
public static int matrizPesos[][];
public static char arbolMinimal[];
public static int distancia[];
public static int linkeoNodos[];
```

but they are accessed which would be a possible cause for `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Sure I understand, but where in the code should initialize these arrays to make the code work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first it would probably be a good idea to fix all the compile-errors (NetBeans marks them in the code for you).

As for that exception, it's telling you that something is `null` on line 98 in `EjemploJFrameConFondo.java`.